# SOAP and JSON services

Tags: rest, web-services, json, soap

Is it possible to produce a web service based on SOAP and on JSON simultaneously?
For what I know it seems that only RESTfull services may use JSON

Comment: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260)

Answer (score 3):

REST doesn't have anything to say about the data protocol you use.

If you read the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer), you'll find out that *"In a RESTful Web service, requests made to a resource's URI will elicit a response that may be in XML, HTML, JSON or some other defined format."*

Naturally, you can write a web service that can return anything, including JSON, and you don't have to follow REST principles to do it.  JSON is just a data transfer format.

Comment: Nitpick: the SOAP body can contain anything. It is possible to put JSON in a `<[CDATA[...]]>` tag in the body. It is possible for the body to be a base64-encoded PNG containing a graphical representation of the XML. Both of those would be dumb to use, but possible.

Comment: I believe most people would be surprised to find a an API that calls itself RESTful but accepts and produces XML instead of JSON. Still, I usually use the combinations REST/JSON and SOAP/XML to avoid confusion.